# PHP TCDPF installation on Windows WAMP Server

Tags: php, wampserver, tcpdf

I have a WAMP installation on my PC that is working fine. I want to install
the TCPDF download, but the installation in structinos are not very clear to
me.
WAMP is installed in c:\wamp. Is that where I am supposed to unzip the TCPDF
package?
Where should I paste the tcpdf directory ?

Answer (score 3):

Just for the ppl who stumble upon this question ,

```
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

is the required file which is to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an existing project that wants to make use of the TCPDF package and that project is in `c:\wamp\www\project1`

Then create a folder under that structure, for example `c:\wamp\www\project1\tcpdf` and place the unzipped files in there.

Then when you want to make use of the TCPDF class from a script in your site lets say

`c:\wamp\www\project1\test_pdf.php` for example, just  :

```
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf_include.php');
```

Comment: I am trying to do as you said but it cannot work with me, It says `Warning: require_once(tcpdf/tcpdf_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project1\test_pdf.php on line 2` and `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'tcpdf/tcpdf_include.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\project1\test_pdf.php on line 2`